# Cannot access files on my computer with ES file explorer app

Tags: lan

I bought the ES app, since the old one no longer exists, and I followed the instructions: 
1.  I entered the app
2. Pressed on the LAN button
3. It found my P.C. and required the password and username, and as I understood it should be my windows 10 username and password (since my OS is windows 10) but it doesn't work! It does nothing!

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The user name on a windows pc actually contains the domain it belongs too as well.  Many things prepend this automatically, many don't.  This is most likley your problem.

Here are a couple of things to try.  Good luck.

1. Can you get to the machine/shares from another windows machine?  If you don't have another machine to test with, this becomes much more difficult.
2. For your user name, try using the IP address, then a backslash, then your user name.  For instance `192.168.1.10\bob`.  The ip address can also be the domain name of the machine as in `bobs_pc\bob` but the ip address never fails.